# How to use NestList for coupled equations?

Tags: iteration

I have a code that works for a single equation.  How to I use NestList for two equation that are coupled?
Below is the code for single equation,

```
 Remove[x, f];
 \[Lambda][r_] := Module[{f, l}, f[x_] := r x (1 - x);
 l[x_] = Log[Abs[D[f[x], x]]];
 Mean[l[NestList[f, 0.1, 1*^2]]]];
 Plot[\[Lambda][r], {r, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01], 
 AxesLabel -> {"r", "\[Lambda](r)"}]
```

The output is

[image]

My attempt for two coupled equation (note: that I used equations uncoupled for testing purpose, but it should work for coupled as well):

```
 Remove[x, y, f];
 \[Lambda][r_] := 
 Module[{f, l}, f[{x_, y_}] := {r x (1 - x), r y (1 - y)};
 l[{x_, y_}] = {Log[Abs[D[First[f[x, y]], x]]], 
 Log[Abs[D[Last[f[x, y]], y]]]};
 Mean[l[NestList[f, {0.1, 0.1},  1*^2]]]];
 ListPlot[Table[\[Lambda][r], {r, 0, 1}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thickness[.01]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"r", "\[Lambda](r)"}]
```

I believe that my source of problem starts with the NestList and Mean.

addendum: My second attempt at the problem,

I almost answered my own question by modifying the code and avoiding Mean Function. However, numerical results are a bit weird.

```
 Remove[x, y, f, lya, \[Lambda], l, xinit, n, iterations, skip, ans1, \
 ans2, ff, ffp, dfp, lya2, xlist2, l2, ndrop2, xinit2, n2]

 iterations = 200;
 skip = 2;

 f[x_] := 4 \[Lambda] x (1 - x);

 lya[l_, xinit_, n_, ndrop_] := (\[Lambda] = l; 
 xlist = Drop[NestList[f, xinit, n],
 ndrop + 1]; Apply[Plus, Log[Abs[f'[xlist]]]]/Length[xlist])

 ans1 = lya[0.91, 0.7, iterations, skip]

 Plot[lya[\[Lambda], 0.7, iterations, skip], {\[Lambda], 0.5, 1.0}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Lambda]", 
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(L\)]\)"}]
```

and the answer is,

```
 0.22816
```

[image: Solution to the code with one function]

Since I want to solve coupled logistic equations say

$x'= a y ( 1 - x)$

$y'= a x ( 1 - y)$

But to make it easier and to verify the correctness of the code I modify equation (uncouple them) to make it simpler,

$x'= a x ( 1 - x)$

$y'= a y ( 1 - y)$

And the above code is modified to handle two equations (list of equations) as follows,

```
 Remove[x, y, \[Lambda], ff, ffp, dfp, lya2, xlist2, l2, ndrop2, 
 xinit2, n2];

 ff[{x_, y_}] = 
 Evaluate[{4 \[Lambda] x (1 - x), 4 \[Lambda] y (1 - y)}];
 ffp[x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate[{4 \[Lambda] x (1 - x), 4 \[Lambda] y (1 - y)}];
 dfp[x_, y_] = Abs[Evaluate[Grad[ffp[x, y], {x, y}] . {1, 1}]];

 lya2[l2_, xinit2_, n2_, ndrop2_] := (\[Lambda] = l2; 
 xlist2 = Drop[NestList[ff, xinit2, n2],
 ndrop2 + 1];
 Apply[Plus, 
 Log[Transpose[
  Function[{x, y}, dfp[x, y]][Sequence @@ Transpose[xlist2]]]]]/
 Length[xlist2])

 ans2 = lya2[0.91, {0.7, 0.7}, iterations, skip]

 Plot[lya2[\[Lambda], {0.7, 0.7}, iterations, skip][[1]], {\[Lambda], 
 0.5, 1.0}, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Lambda]", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(L\)]\)"}]

 Plot[lya2[\[Lambda], {0.7, 0.7}, iterations, skip][[2]], {\[Lambda], 
 0.5, 1.0}, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Lambda]", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(L\)]\)"}]

 (*   compare answers  *)
 ans1 == ans1
 ans1 == ans2[[1]]  
 ans1 == ans2[[2]]
```

and the answer for the above code is

```
 {0.243622, 0.243622}
```

[image]

[image]

```
 True
 False
 False
```

For iterations=30 I get all True.  False starts after 40 iterations.  It is puzzling to me as to why it happens.  Equations are identical.  Perhaps, additional functions used in second code add error to it.  Or perhaps my approach is not correct even though I am getting the same plots. But if you try iterations=5000 and skip=2000, the code for listed equations shows completely wrong plots.

**Update 1:**

Following suggestions by @Varnavides, it worked for this particular equation except for some other equation, see below:

```
 Clear[ff, dfp, lya, ff2, dfp2, lya2]

Remove[ff, dfp, lya, ff2, dfp2, lya2]

ff3[\[Lambda]_][{x_, y_}] = {4 \[Lambda] x, 4 \[Lambda] y (1 -  y)};

ff2[\[Lambda]_][{x_, y_}] = {4 \[Lambda] x (1 - x), 
4 \[Lambda] y (1 - y)};
dfp2[\[Lambda]_][{x_, y_}] = 
Abs[Grad[ff2[\[Lambda]][{x, y}], {x, y}] . {1, 1}];

lya2[\[Lambda]2_, xinit2_, n2_, ndrop2_] := 
Block[{xlist2}, 
xlist2 = Drop[NestList[ff2[\[Lambda]2], xinit2, n2], ndrop2 + 1];
Log[Transpose[dfp2[\[Lambda]2][Transpose[xlist2]]]] // Mean]

lya2[0.91, {0.7, 0.7}, 4, 1]

{-0.152808, -0.152808}

xlist2 = Drop[NestList[ff2[0.91], {0.7, 0.7}, 4], 2]

{{0.655537, 0.655537}, {0.821942, 0.821942}, {0.532727, 0.532727}}

xlist3 = Transpose[xlist2]

{{0.655537, 0.821942, 0.532727}, {0.655537, 0.821942, 0.532727}}

dfp2[0.91][Transpose[xlist2]]

{{1.13231, 2.34374, 0.238251}, {1.13231, 2.34374, 0.238251}}
```

Equation ff2 is is fine, but equation ff3 is not.  It fails to Transpose.  Using ff3, there is a missing curly brackets in output.  Why curly brackets are vanishing?

Answer (score 4):

### Edit 01:

I suspect your issue arises from using global variables in your function definitions. Here's a simple re-write of your code, passing `λ` as a parameter and using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to localize the `xlist` variable. The results seem to agree to large iteration numbers:

```
Clear[ff, dfp, lya, ff2, dfp2, lya2]
ff[λ_][x_] = 4 λ x (1 - x);
dfp[λ_][x_] = Abs[D[ff[λ][x], x]];

lya[λ_, xinit_, n_, ndrop_] := Block[{xlist},
  xlist = Drop[NestList[ff[λ], xinit, n], ndrop + 1];
  Log[dfp[λ][xlist]] // Mean]

ff2[λ_][{x_, y_}] = {4 λ x (1 - x), 
   4 λ y (1 - y)};
dfp2[λ_][{x_, y_}] = 
  Abs[Grad[ff2[λ][{x, y}], {x, y}] . {1, 1}];

lya2[λ2_, xinit2_, n2_, ndrop2_] := Block[{xlist2},
  xlist2 = Drop[NestList[ff2[λ2], xinit2, n2], ndrop2 + 1];
  Log[Transpose[dfp2[λ2][Transpose[xlist2]]]] // Mean]

lya[0.91, 0.7, 200, 2]
lya2[0.91, {0.7, 0.7}, 200, 2]
```

`0.243622`
`{0.243622, 0.243622}`

### Original Post:

I'll use a canonical example of a coupled iterative equation to illustrate the concept, namely the De-jong attractor:

```
dejong[{x_, y_}] = With[{a = 1.6, b = 1.9, c = 0.3, d = 1.5}, 
{Sin[a y] - Cos[b x],Sin[c x] - Cos[d y]}]
NestList[dejong, {1., 1.}, 10^4] // Point // Graphics
```

[image]

The two things to note are:

1. Make sure your function accepts the same form of arguments as it outputs, i.e. you would change your function from `f[x_, y_]={..,..}` to `f[{x_, y_}]={..,..}`
2. The third argument of `NestList` is the number of iterations, so it expects a single integer value.

With these two changes your example above gets close to working, although if I understand correctly you'd want to express `l[{x_,y_}]={..,..}` symbolically and simply Nest over that. Note that currently your example above passes the entire list output to `l`. This works for your single equation case as `Log` and `Abs` are `Listable` and thread over their arguments.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I still run into problems.  This time Function Mean.  I updated my attempted code with your ideas.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps editing your question using some math formulas could help? 
Currently your single equation formulation is doing the following (e.g. for r=0.1) : iterating `f_{n+1} = 0.1*f_n*(1-f_n)` for 100 iterations; taking the log of the absolute value of the symbolic derivative of _each_ of these `l_n = Log[Abs[0.1*(1-f_n)-0.1*f_n]]` and then taking the mean of those 100 values. Is this really what you meant to do? Or were you trying to do something like `l_{n+1}=Log[Abs[0.1*(1-l_n)-0.1*l_n]]` and iterate that for 100 iterations?

Comment: I am just trying to convert code from one equation of f=equ to code that can do f=(equ1,equ2) using the same format.  Eventually later on be capable to extent to more than just two equation.   Looks like it is more complicated than I originally though.

Comment: Please edit your question to give an example (using equations) of two coupled iterative equations you'd like to solve. The way it's currently set up, you can do something like this `\[Lambda][r_] := Module[{f, l},
  f[{x_, y_}] := {r x (1 - x), r y (1 - y)};
  l[{x_, y_}] = {
    Log[Abs[D[First[f[{x, y}]], x]]],
    Log[Abs[D[Last[f[{x, y}]], y]]]
    };
  Mean[Transpose[l[Transpose[NestList[f, {0.1, 0.1}, 1*^2]]]]]]` but it doesn't seem like what you want to do.. Again, note that the `Transpose`s are needed since _the entire list_ output of `NestList` gets passed to `l`

Comment: I do not know if you are qualified to answer this question or should I ask a moderator etc, You see, I have almost solved the problem using slightly different approach (avoiding Mean function).  I am getting the plots for pairs which are the same as single.  However, when I check iterations for small iteration  the solution numbers are the same but for large iterations numbers do not agree even plots change) Question: 1)  Should I post a separate question/problem? 2) should I update this Question/problem? Should I add answer to it?

Comment: Either editing your post, or answering yourself are appropriate. If you still have unanswered questions you'd like help with, editing will likely be most useful to you.

Comment: I added extra code and my second solution attempt.  Almost there.  A new problem pops up which is numerical.

Comment: Looks like equation test 1 generates (scalar, vector) and test 2 generates (scalar, scalar).  The test has (vector, vector).  Scalars are resulted without curly brackets.  Is there a way (shorthand) to prevent scalar displayed without curly brackets?